# retrieve .svg image uploaded to mysql using php.

Tags: javascript, php, svg

I uploaded .svg images to the database using PHP. Now I like to retrieve those images to my different canvas through image.src = '';. Is it possible to retrieve or I need to use other ways to do such. I am learning to SQL and PHP, help me here.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');

  canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var image = new Image();
  image.src = '';

  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #ccc; display: block; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: left; border-color: transparent; ">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

'src' points to the URL where to get this image.

You can either create a PHP file which will "download" the image from your database and display it, the src will pont to that PHP file. Or you can encode the image as base64 and use the src `data:image/png;base64,(base64 image here)`

Comment: It is .svg file. Is it possible to encode .svg asbase64?? I tried but I didn't found solution.